# How to use an unpackaged node module in Electron packaged build (trash npm)

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, packaging, recycle-bin

I have an Electron app, and I'm using the [trash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trash) npm module. In my code, the only way that I can import the package is like so:

```
let trash;
import('trash').then((trashModule) => { trash = trashModule.default || trashModule; });
```

And later in my script, I raise the trash function like so `trash([imagePath]);` This works fine when testing my Electron app via `npm run start`. But things are different in a packaged build.

So in my `/dist/win-unpacked/` folder, I run the exe and trash is recognized and works properly. However, if I install the application via the setup exe in `/dist/`, it fails to find trash. It can **only find** the trash module if I run the exe in `repo_path/dist/win-unpacked/`.

The one difference about the trash module compared to all the other modules I use is that it does not pack into the asar file. It lives, unpacked, under a folder called `app.asar.unpacked` right next to the asar file.

TL;DR I want trash to work in packaged builds. Thoughts? Help?

I tried disabling asar in package.json, and I was able to get trash to work in packaged builds. However, I want to build with asar enabled.